# Trying to modify multiaudience environment

Tags: environments, arguments

I'm using the multiaudience package - works pretty nice. Here is an example

```
\usepackage{multiaudience}
\SetNewAudience{internGER}
\SetNewAudience{externGER}
\DefCurrentAudience{internGER}
...
\begin{shownto}{internGER, externGER}
text for everyone
\begin{shownto}{internGER}
text for internals only
\end{shownto}
\end{shownto}
```

Now I would love to create an extra-option, that allows me to "mark" (text in red or underline or something like this) the internal text. That will make text-approval much easier, as you do not have to check both documents, but only one.

So I tried to recreate the shownto environment

```
  \let\oldshownto\shownto
  \let\endoldshownto\endshownto
  \renewenvironment{shownto}[1][]{%
  THIS TEXT WILL BE VISIBLE TO #1 :\\
 \oldshownto
  }{ %
  END OF VISIBLE TEXT\\
  \endoldshownto
  }
```

my plan was to use some "if-magic" based on argument #1, unfortunately there is no content in #1. What is wrong with this?

Here is the full minimal example - its compiling

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{multiaudience}
\SetNewAudience{internGER}
\SetNewAudience{externGER}
\DefCurrentAudience{internGER}
%\DefCurrentAudience{externGER}

\let\oldshownto\shownto
\let\endoldshownto\endshownto
\renewenvironment{shownto}[1][]{%
-THIS TEXT WILL BE VISIBLE TO #1-, 
\oldshownto
}{ %
-END-\\
\endoldshownto
}

\begin{document}
\begin{shownto}{internGER, externGER}
text for everyone.


\begin{shownto}{internGER}
text for internals only
\end{shownto}
\end{shownto}
\end{document}
```

Thanks
Georg

Comment: I added the compling example

Answer (score 2):

You are defining the environment to take an *optional* argument, which by default is empty, but you want (1) the environment to take a *mandatory* argument, and (2) to pass this argument to the original environment.

However, the `{shownto}` environment is defined by `\NewEnviron` (in a way which makes me think that the author kind of misunderstood its usage...), so I'd take a different approach:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multiaudience}
\SetNewAudience{internGER}
\SetNewAudience{externGER}
\DefCurrentAudience{internGER}
%\DefCurrentAudience{externGER}

% original definition
%\NewEnviron{shownto}[1]{%
%  \@MULTAU@shownfalse\@MULTAU@includetrue
%  \setkeys{MULTAU}{#1}%
%  \if@MULTAU@shown\BODY\fi}
\makeatletter
\RenewEnviron{shownto}[1]{%
   \@MULTAU@shownfalse\@MULTAU@includetrue
   \setkeys{MULTAU}{#1}%
   \if@MULTAU@shown
   [START TEXT SHOWN TO #1]%
   \BODY
   [END]%
   \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{shownto}{internGER, externGER}
text for everyone.


\begin{shownto}{internGER}
text for internals only
\end{shownto}
\end{shownto}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is working fine.... how can I do the same for the \showto{} command. Difinition is `\long\def\showto#1#2{\@MULTAU@shownfalse\@MULTAU@includetrue
  \setkeys{MULTAU}{#1}%
  \if@MULTAU@shown#2\fi
  \@MULTAU@showntrue\@MULTAU@includetrue}`