# Further question regarding multiaudience

Tags: renewcommand

I was able to get an advanced version of the `multiaudience` package running. [Original Post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/693146/trying-to-modify-multiaudience-environment/693150#693150)
This code here is working pretty well:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{multiaudience}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{red}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\SetNewAudience{internGER}
\SetNewAudience{externGER}
\DefCurrentAudience{internGER}
%\DefCurrentAudience{externGER}

% original definition
%\NewEnviron{shownto}[1]{%
%  \@MULTAU@shownfalse\@MULTAU@includetrue
%  \setkeys{MULTAU}{#1}%
%  \if@MULTAU@shown\BODY\fi}
\makeatletter
\RenewEnviron{shownto}[1]{%
   \@MULTAU@shownfalse\@MULTAU@includetrue
   \setkeys{MULTAU}{#1}%
   \if@MULTAU@shown
   \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{internGER}}{
   
   \textcolor{red}{\scriptsize\textit{[Following red text will be published in the internal version only: ]}\\
   \normalsize\BODY}}{\BODY}%
   
   \fi
}
\makeatother

%\long\def\showto#1#2{\@MULTAU@shownfalse\@MULTAU@includetrue
% \setkeys{MULTAU}{#1}%
%  \if@MULTAU@shown#2\fi
%  \@MULTAU@showntrue\@MULTAU@includetrue}
\makeatletter
\def\showto#1#2{%
   \@MULTAU@shownfalse\@MULTAU@includetrue
   \setkeys{MULTAU}{#1}%
   \if@MULTAU@shown \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{internGER}}{\textcolor{red}{\scriptsize\textit{[Following red text will be published in the internal version only: ] }\normalsize #2}}{#2}\fi
  \@MULTAU@showntrue\@MULTAU@includetrue
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{shownto}{internGER, externGER}
\section{One}
Text for everyone. \lipsum[1-1]

\begin{shownto}{internGER}
Text for internals only. \lipsum[2-2][3]
\end{shownto}
Again a text for everyone. \lipsum[2-2][3] \showto{internGER}{And only an internal text}
\end{shownto}
\lipsum[3-3]
\begin{shownto}{internGER}
\section{Two}
Text for internals only. \lipsum[4-4]
\end{shownto}
\begin{shownto}{internGER, externGER}
\section{Three}
\lipsum[5-5][5]
\end{shownto}

\end{document}
```

[image: Latexoutput]

However I'm facing two issues:

1. One can see that the section title "2 Two" is writen in black letters. (This does not happen when using article instead of `scrartcl`.)
2. I would like to create a main switch around this, something like "forceAllAudienceOn". When the variable is false, `LaTeX` should behave as normal without modifications.